# Character in Combobox/Listbox instead of whitespace

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In my userform listbox/combobox i get the character shown in the picture where there is supposed to be a whitespace.

[image]

It is probably really simple but i have no idea how to get rid of this.

The text in the combobox it occurs to is a range that was put into an array.

Comment: That's a **pilcrow** character (¶ or ASCII 182). It is typically used to signify a carriage return (vbCrLf or Chr(13) & Chr(10)). Try replacing vbCrLf with Chr(32) (a space) or replacing Chr(182) with a space. One last option might be to replace Chr(10) with Chr(32) but that is just a linefeed (vbLF), not vbCrLf (Chr(13) & Chr(10)).

Comment: Stupid question maybe but how do i do this?

Comment: How are you populating the listbox/combobox? Edit your question to include the code used or a description of the method.

Comment: Edited, hope this is enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it for space and chr(180) from range *(r)* in control *(c)*, later on you can recharge it during import and export data from control:

```
if instr(r.value,Chr(182))>0 then c.add replace(r.value, chr(182),chr(32)+chr(180)
if instr(c.text,chr(32)+chr(180))>0 then r.value = replace(c.text, chr(32)+chr(180),chr(13))
```